Как подключить Яндекс карты к приложению на React 18?
Видел данное руководство https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/dg/concepts/integrations/reactify Но, честно говоря, ничего из него не понял. Например, куда мне вставлять данный код? в index.tsx?
const ymaps3Reactify = await ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-reactify');
const reactify = ymaps3Reactify.reactify.bindTo(React, ReactDOM);
const {YMap, YMapDefaultSchemeLayer, YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer, YMapMarker} = reactify.module(ymaps3);

Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в JS, поэтому по данному руководству я не понял, что конкретно я должен делать. Так что хотелось бы, чтобы кто-то, кто занимался подключением официального апи яндекс карт к React 18 рассказал, как это правильно делается.

Код указывается в index.tsx. Эти строчки отвечают за импорт модуля @yandex/ymaps3-reactify — обычное подключение API происходит с помощью добавления строчки  в HTML-код вашего приложения, промис является следующим шагом инициализации. Подробнее о разных способах подключения и инициализации API вы можете прочитать в разделе Документации Подключение API.
